What is :out after a shell call to execute some command?
Considering:
user=> (require '[babashka.process :refer [shell]])
nil
user=> (def j
  (-> (shell {:out :string :err "/dev/null"} "ls")
      :out some-func))

I understand that {:out :string :err "/dev/null"} is a map of a kind of options used to mold behavior for the shell command to run.
Then, at the next line.
:out, I understand it's a keyword that corresponds to stdout. I also know that it can be used to retrieve the corresponding value from a map.
But I don't understand how :out some-func can be used to call the function some-func.
Where does the macro -> place the result of the line (shell ...)?  I suppose that after :out.  So, the :out value would be extracted from the map of results of the (shell...) line, but how is it used as argument to some-func?
It is not even inside parenthesis.  Why not?

The so-called "thread first" -> macro does two things:

It makes sure that every form passed to it is wrapped in (...)
It chains the forms so that (-> (a) (b) (c) ...) becomes (... (c (b (a))))

So in your case, the result is (some-func (:out (shell ...))).

So, if every form passed is wrapped in (...), why (json/parse-string true) is inside parenthesis, in this example: (-> (sh "curl" "-H" "Accept:application/json" "https://some_url)                       :out                       (json/parse-string true)) ?

It doesn't wrap every form unconditionally, it makes sure every form is wrapped. In other words, if a form is inside (...) already, the macro doesn't wrap it a second time. But if it's not inside (...), it adds the parens.
